# Filtering a row value if it already included in the previous

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some problems to check if an element of a list in one column match itself from another column.

Specifically I have a dataset such this:

```
Student          Student representatives
Mary Jane        [Mary Jane, Lucas]
Christopher      [Matt]
Jonathan         [Luke]
Barbara          [Barbara, Martin]
```

What I should do is to select each row and check student's value with student representatives. If they match, I should remove the element from the array.

Expected output:

```
Student          Student representatives
Mary Jane        [Lucas]
Christopher      [Matt]
Jonathan         [Luke]
Barbara          [Martin]
```

Could you please give me some advice on how to do this? thank.

Comment: You show lists, but you tagged `numpy`.  How are your columns organized?  Are you using a dataframe in `pandas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'r using a `pandas dataframe`,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "stu": ['Mary Jane', 'Christopher', 'Jonathan', 'Barbara'],
    "stu_rep": [['Mary Jane', 'Lucas'], ['Matt'], ['Luke'], ['Barbara', 'Martin']],
})

df.assign(
    stu_rep = df.apply(lambda x: [s for s in x['stu_rep'] if s != x['stu']], axis=1)
)
```

---

```
           stu   stu_rep
0    Mary Jane   [Lucas]
1  Christopher    [Matt]
2     Jonathan    [Luke]
3      Barbara  [Martin]
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a working bit from this newbie - hope it helps --- thought I agree it is not the best solution...

lets say

```py
student = ['Mary Jane', 'Christopher', 'Jonathan', 'Barbara']
student_rep = [['Mary Jane', 'Lucas'], ['Matt'], ['Luke'], ['Barbara', 'Martin']]
student_rep_new = []

for i in range(len(student)):
    test = []
    for j in range(len(student_rep[i])):
        if student_rep[i][j] != student[i]:
            test.append(student_rep[i][j])

           # student_rep_new.append([student_rep[i][j]])
    student_rep_new.append(test)

print(student)
print(student_rep)
print(student_rep_new)
```

**Input:**
['Mary Jane', 'Christopher', 'Jonathan', 'Barbara']
and
[['Mary Jane', 'Lucas'], ['Matt'], ['Luke'], ['Barbara', 'Martin']]

**Output:**
[['Lucas'], ['Matt'], ['Luke'], ['Martin']]

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the data as dictionary. Then it is fairly simple.

```
dictNames = {'Mary Jane':['Mary Jane','Lucas'] , 'Christopher': ['Matt'],'Jonathan':['Luke'],'Barbara': ['Barbara', 'Martin']}

for k,v in dictNames.items():
    dictNames[k] = [x for x in v if x != k]

print(dictNames)
```